# align left and right two JLabels in a "North" BorderLayout

Tags: java, alignment, jlabel

I am using `BorderLayout` for my application. 
`setLayout(new BorderLayout());`
I need to align two `JLabels` in left and right in the `"NORTH"` of the `JPanel`.

Here is my code:

```
JPanel top = new JPanel();
top.add(topTxtLabel);
top.add(logoutTxtLabel);
add(BorderLayout.PAGE_START, top);
```

So I need topTxtLabel in left and logoutTxtLabel in right.
I tried to implement Border Layout again to use "WEST" and "EAST", but it didn't worked. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your application consists of a `JFrame` with `BorderLayout` you could try this: Set the layout mode of your `JPanel` again to `BorderLayout`. Add the panel in the north of the frame. Then add the 2 `JLabels` in the east and west. You can also replace the `JFrame` with another `JPanel`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Main();
    }

    Main()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel left = new JLabel("LEFT");
        JLabel right = new JLabel("RIGHT");
        JPanel top = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        top.add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        top.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(new JLabel("Another dummy Label"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: as I said, I tried to combine BorderLayout WEST and EAST in a main JPanel NORTH and it didn't work......any other ideas?? :(

Comment: It worked for me (see my edit). That's what I interpreted from your question. If you intend a different behavior then please specify more specifically what you need.